# Directiva v-on no está funcionando VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy trasteando con VueJS y mi codigo HTML es el siguiente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <main v-if="mensaje!=null">
        he recibido el mensaje! : {{ mensaje }}
    </main>

    <input type="button" value="Agregame" v-on:click="agregarTarea"></input>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script> 
    <!-- importante -->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y mi código de JS es este :

```js
/* Vue.js */

let myVue = new Vue({
    el:'main',
    data:{
        mensaje: 'hola'
    },
    methods:{
        agregarTarea() {
            console.log('Funciona');
        }
    }
});
```

El comportamiento esperado sería un `console.log` con un mensaje 'Funciona' cada vez que apretas el botón, sin embargo, nada. Ni errores en JS, ni del Framework, ni nada, la consola del navegador no responde nada cuando pulso. He mirado 8 o 9 ejemplos por Internet y todos lo hacen de la misma manera, sin embargo a mi no me va.

Al sustituir la directiva `v-on:click` por `onclick=...` clásica de JS, y asignarle una función idéntica (obviamente fuera del objeto Vue), realiza la tarea correctamente...

No creo que tenga nada que ver, pero estoy probando todo esto mediante Express, un Framework de Node, dejo el código también por si acaso:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use('/events/index.html', express.static(__dirname+"/../events/index.html"));
app.use('/events/main.js', express.static(__dirname+"/../events/main.js"));

app.listen(port, (err) => {
    console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
  })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que el input esta fuera del elemento `main` que es el contenedor del vue.  Simplemente agrega el input al main asi:

```js
let myVue = new Vue({
    el:'main',
    data:{
        mensaje: 'hola'
    },
    methods:{
        agregarTarea: function(event) {
            console.log('Funciona');
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
    
    <main v-if="mensaje!=null">
        he recibido el mensaje! : {{ mensaje }}
        <input type="button" value="Agregame" v-on:click="agregarTarea"></input>
    </main>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script> 
    <!-- importante -->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```